# How do I search in Gmail such that email address is also included?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I searched for a car hire email in Google's Gmail, knowing the name of the company I had used. However, frustratingly, the email booking included a lot of images with their name, but the only text including their name was the email address. To be more specific for the purpose of clarifying the question, I searched for `argus`, and the email with booking details was `noreply@arguscarhire.com`.

Searching for `argus`, only came up with emails where `argus` was mentioned in the content of the email.

Is there a way to look for the search string in both the content and email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

From the Gmail search bar you can add various flags to narrow your search, e.g.,
`from:argus "car hire"` searches for the string "car hire" in any email from an address containing "argus". So if you know the email address but not its content you could search `from:noreply@arguscarhire.com`.

Comment: will "from:argus" find all emails where the string "argus" is included in sender's email?
Is there any way to check if argus is included in sender's email, to/cc email, OR content?

Comment: It all follows the same format, `cc:'string' ` or `to:'string'` or `bcc:'string'` or even `label:trash` (or any other folder or label

Comment: Just note that a single search will show results that match to ALL search criteria, not just closest or "best" match. So you may need to do a succession of searches if you are wanting a variety of sent/recieved/cc'ed etc results

Comment: And (to answer your question) yes, it will return all that have argus in the email address. Try searching `from:gmail` or `from:.com` and have a look at the results